# How Can I Optimize Images

Tags: jquery, wordpress, performance, elementor, pagespeed

I have built a website for my ortfolio using Elementor Pro. However, everytime I load the site the logo seems to load a few milliseconds slower than the rest of the page and I cannot get it all to load at the same time?

Secondly, it is relatively slow to load on mobile and I have been advised to Eliminate render-blocking resources - what is the best way to go about this?

jacarywebdesign.com/

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your logo seems to have the below opacity transition rule. Try erasing it and see if it works or setting `transition: opacity 0ms;`.

```
.lazyloaded {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 400ms;
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}
```

Regarding eliminating render-blocking resources you can check the [WP-Rocket post](https://wp-rocket.me/google-core-web-vitals-wordpress/eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-css/).

Answer (score 0):

A look at the element inspector in Chrome shows that your logo is "lazy loaded". The CSS class `lazyloaded` has `transition` set to `opacity 400ms`. Reset this to `0ms`.

From:

```
.lazyloaded {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 400ms;
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}
```

To:

```
.lazyloaded {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0ms;
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}
```

As for your question regarding eliminating render-blocking resources, here's a detail explanation of how to do it manually: [See here](https://gtmetrix.com/blog/how-to-eliminate-render-blocking-resources/).

If you would rather go with plugins, [read this article](https://wpengine.com/resources/remove-render-blocking-javascript-css-wordpress/).

Answer (score 0):

You have so many JS files, they are blocking rendering.
The Browser cannot start rendering until the fonts, JS, and CSS are all loaded.

These are the render blocking files.
[LINK to speed results from webpagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/220912_BiDc22_DA1/)

```
91 ms: https://jacarywebdesign.com/wp-content/cache/minify/d52ed.js
673 ms: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
195 ms: https://jacarywebdesign.com/wp-content/cache/minify/9af47.js
63 ms: https://jacarywebdesign.com/wp-content/cache/minify/f2459.js
180 ms: https://jacarywebdesign.com/wp-content/cache/minify/b74df.js
86 ms: https://jacarywebdesign.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/assets/js/animated-headline.ffb4bb4ce1b16b11446d.bundle.min.js 
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CRoboto+Slab%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CGothic+A1%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CQuestrial%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CAverage+Sans%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic&display=auto&ver=6.0.2
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
```